# Move element to right margin without removing from HTML flow with CSS

Tags: html, css, position

I have a column of fixed width centered on the page. Since the viewport varies, the margin is unknown. I would like to move it to the left edge of the screen without removing it from the HTML flow.

```
<main class="centered" style="width:750px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">
...
  <figure class="imagefullwidth" style="width:100vw">
    <img src="image.jpg">
  </figure>
...
</main>
```

That should look something like:

```
       _______main_______
      |                 |
      |                 |
 _____|______figure_____|_____     
|                             |
|                             |     
|                             |     
|_____________________________|     
      |                 |
      |                 |
      |                 |
      |_________________|
```

Of course, I tried `position: absolute; left: 0` on `<figure>` but that took it out of the HTML flow. I tried `position: absolute;` on the image and though I can create a larger image than its container, `left:0` only puts the image at the left edge of the `<main>` (plus that allowed `<figure>` to collapse to height 0 and I don't know the height of the image to give it a height).

Negative margins don't help because I don't know the width of the margin at any particular viewport width. `float: left` doesn't work because it floats within its container.

I can't modify the HTML because it comes from a CMS. But there are lots of wrappers and stuff I can style.

Can you think of a way to do this with pure CSS, without JS?

[image: Attempting to make the image larger than its container - left:0 can't break out of main container]

Comment: share your screenshot please.

Comment: @ParTha Not sure how that will help, but happy to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the html and visual example provided the below css seems to accomplish what you're after. [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/7tv01cgw/)

```
.centered {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 750px;
}

.imagefullwidth {
  width: initial !important;
}

.imagefullwidth img {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: I had to set `min-width: 100vw` to break it out of its container, but yes, it worked. Awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

i do not know why you want to do so but if you want to move a column to a left side you can do something like this .

```
<main class="centered" style="width:750px;margin-left:0;margin-right:auto">

  <div class="imagefullwidth" style="width:100vw">
    <img src="image.jpg">
  </div>

</main>
```

here you are making changes in first line .

```
 <main class="centered" style="width:750px;margin-left:0;margin-right:auto">
```

where margin left is 0 so that it can move column to left site . because having margin auto it tries to align in center.

as you said this code come from CMS . it could be possible that this will not work because there would be a CSS file that is overrding this property .

Comment: "I can't modify the HTML because it comes from a CMS. But there are lots of wrappers and stuff I can style." Yeah, I can't modify the HTML, but I can modify the CSS as much as I like (or actually add more CSS that overrides the default CSS). I wouldn't wan't to set `<main>` to `margin-left:0` because then the rest of the contents wouldn't be centered or be in a 750px column.